# RapidJSON pointer notation for member of object in array of objects

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I have a document that has an array of objects. I know how to retrieve the object itself using pointer notation.

```
rapidjson::Value* ptr = GetValueByPointer(document, "/object1/object2/array/0");
```

I can then access members of that object as needed.

```
(*ptr)["name"].GetString();
```

But I'm trying to figure out how to get to `name` directly for a specific index in the array using the pointer notation above.

I tried:

```
rapidjson::Value* name = GetValueByPointer(document, "/object1/object2/array/0/name");
```

But `name` is NULL. How can I do this?